# rvest: how to change radio button value in a form

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using `rvest` to do some webscraping, and I am training on tripadvisor. I don't manage to set a radio button to the proper value in order to have all comments :

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187438-d12699400-Reviews-Trattoria_Mamma_Franca-Malaga_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andalucia.html"
session <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(session)[[3]]
```

which gives the form

```
<form> 'taplc_location_review_filter_controls_0_form' (POST /SetReviewFilter#REVIEWS)
  <input checkbox> 'filterRating': 5
  <input checkbox> 'filterRating': 4
  <input checkbox> 'filterRating': 3
  <input checkbox> 'filterRating': 2
  <input checkbox> 'filterRating': 1
  <input hidden> 'filterRating': 
  <input checkbox> 'filterSegment': 3
  <input checkbox> 'filterSegment': 2
  <input checkbox> 'filterSegment': 5
  <input checkbox> 'filterSegment': 1
  <input checkbox> 'filterSegment': 4
  <input hidden> 'filterSegment': 
  <input checkbox> 'filterSeasons': 1
  <input checkbox> 'filterSeasons': 2
  <input checkbox> 'filterSeasons': 3
  <input checkbox> 'filterSeasons': 4
  <input hidden> 'filterSeasons': 
  <input radio> 'filterLang': ALL
  <input radio> 'filterLang': en
  <input radio> 'filterLang': es
  <input radio> 'filterLang': it
  <input radio> 'filterLang': fr
  <input radio> 'filterLang': nl
  <input radio> 'filterLang': ru
  <input radio> 'filterLang': sv
  <input radio> 'filterLang': da
  <input radio> 'filterLang': de
  <input radio> 'filterLang': no
  <input radio> 'filterLang': pl
  <input radio> 'filterLang': pt
  <input hidden> 'returnTo': #REVIEWS
```

I would like to set `filterLang` to `ALL`

```
filledform <- set_values(pgform,
                         filterLang = "ALL")
submit_form(session,filledform)
```

gives me the error:

```
Error: Could not find possible submission target.
```

What submission should I use ? Can I use rvest, or should I try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185501/r-language-how-to-make-a-click-on-webpage-using-rvest-or-rcurl) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is not related to the radio buttons but rather to the fact that the form you are trying to submit is lacking a `submit` button which `rvest` requires when trying to submit a form.

As a workaround for your example you can change the field type of the field `returnTo` to `submit` and set its value to the URL of the page itself, just like this:

```
pgform$fields[['returnTo']]$type = 'submit'
pgform$fields[['returnTo']]$value = url
```

Then you can set the language option as expected so things like

```
filledform <- set_values(pgform, filterLang = 'it')
```

or

```
filledform <- set_values(pgform, filterLang = 'ALL')
```

should work to set the language filter to Italian, or all languages, respectively.

Similarly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170997/211221), when you do something like this

```
url <- 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187438-d12699400-Reviews-Trattoria_Mamma_Franca-Malaga_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andalucia.html'
session <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(session)[[3]]
pgform$fields[['returnTo']]$type = 'submit'
pgform$fields[['returnTo']]$value = url
filledform <- set_values(pgform, filterLang = 'ALL')
result <- submit_form(session, filledform)
```

you would rather get the whole page whereas you would get only the content using the following code

```
url <- 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187438-d12699400-Reviews-Trattoria_Mamma_Franca-Malaga_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andalucia.html'
session <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(session)[[3]]
pgform$fields[['returnTo']]$type = 'submit'
pgform$fields[['returnTo']]$value = url
filledform <- set_values(pgform, filterLang = 'ALL')
result <- submit_form(session, filledform, submit = NULL, httr::add_headers('x-requested-with' = 'XMLHttpRequest'))
```

Since you are trying to interact with a rather complex website which makes heavy use of JavaScript and `XMLHttpRequest` you might be better off switching from `rvest` to an approach with better support for such technologies, such as `RSelenium`.

Comment: I will have a look to `RSelenium`. `rvest` just looked easier to start with. Do you have a good starting point or doc to advise ?

Comment: I have an additional question : why the main form find restaurant doesn't appear in html_form for "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants" ? How do you access it with `rvest` ?

Comment: As far as I can see the site you mentioned does not contain any form for searching and submitting, so I presume these actions are solely implemented using JavaScript. Selenium also avoids that you have to care for such implementation details.

Comment: The official documentation of RSelenium provides a good introduction to its [basic usage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html). Apart from that, I would also suggest the documentation of Selenium to get a grasp of its [concepts](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp) and understand what makes it different from the approach that tools like `rvest` use.